# SELECT array from table and join on jsonb object in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Not sure how this is possible but no answer I've found is remotely close.

Lets say I have table A and Table B. Table B has a jsonb column with both the key and values are integers. e.g. `{"10000":"12345678","10002":"12345680}`

I want to query a Table A and the results from A check if one of the results is in that json object by key and return the val. The values is a unix timestamp and i want to sort on that.

I've tried various jsonb functions but nothing is close to what I'm trying

I tried something like this and just get an `error`.

```
SELECT a.from_id, b.*, info.id, info.date 
FROM table a, 
     table b, 
     jsonb_to_recordset(jsonb_each_text(b.mem_ids)) AS info(id int, date int) 
WHERE a.from_id = info.id 
ORDER BY info.date 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

I only what to get the first result that it finds in the json object that matches id from table A. 
Not sure how to accomplish with using a jsonb column.

**Update**:
example tables

```
table a
|from_id | to_id |
 100001  | 100005
 100002  | 100005
 100003  | 100005


table b
|   id       |            mem_ids|
     1       | {"100075":"12345678","100003":"12345680}
```

So what I'm trying to do is a query or some sort of join, that will get the results from_id from table a based on providing the to_id in the case 100005, and from those results see if there is a json obejct with a key that matches one of the from_ids.  If so, return that value from the key that was matched. 
Seems a bit complicated but unfortunately thats the structure right now.

Comment: Add some sample rows in **text** format from your table to easily simulate your issue.

Comment: I didn't get it. Please add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can transform you jsonb column using subquery to table look

```
select jsonb_object_keys(mem_ids) as id, mem_ids->>jsonb_object_keys(mem_ids) as date  
    from (
         select '{"10000":123,"10002":456}'::jsonb as mem_ids
         union 
         select '{"20000":987,"20002":159}'::jsonb as mem_ids
    ) as b;
```

Then ofcourse you can simply join it result with you main table by INNER JOIN

```
select from_id, to_id, date from (
        select 100001 as from_id, 100005 as to_id
        union 
        select 100002 as from_id, 100005 as to_id
        union 
        select 100003 as from_id, 100005 as to_id) as a
    inner join  (
        select jsonb_object_keys(mem_ids)::int as id, mem_ids->>jsonb_object_keys(mem_ids) as date  from (
            select 1 as id, '{"100075":12345678,"100003":12345680}'::jsonb as mem_ids
            union 
            select 2 as id, '{"200075":987654321,"200003":1592648}'::jsonb as mem_ids
        ) as b
    ) as b on from_id = id
ORDER BY date desc
LIMIT 1;
```